# Does not recognize the Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I press debug it come up With error "Method or data member not found" in relation to worksheet "Jobcard Master"??

```
Private Sub Toolpod_Width_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbooks
    Dim BodyLength As Variant
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Job Card Master")
    Set BodyLength = ws.Range("A10").Value
    
    Select Case Toolpod_Width.Value
    
    Case ("600")
        BodyLength -680
     
    Case ("800")
        BodyLength -880
    
    Case ("900")
        BodyLength -980
    
    Case ("1000")
        BodyLength -1080
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `ws` and `wb` variables should be declared as `Worksheet`, not `Worksheets`, and `Workbook`, not `Workbooks`

Comment: I took the s away from both but it does not recognize the workbook or worksheet now??

Comment: You should also include the file extension in the `Set wb = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker")` line.

Comment: If you do this `Set wb = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker.xlsx")` the code expects that this workbook is already open in Excel. Is that the case? If not you would need to open it from your hard drive using the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: The workbook is open. Now I`ve put the .xlsm on to the workbook it just won`t recognize the worksheet?

Comment: @user14435479 See my answer below. You need to be very precise when writing code. One typo and it doesn't work. In your text you write *worksheet "Jobcard Master"* but in your code it is named `Worksheets("Job Card Master")` if you are too sloppy with your names the worksheet won't be found because `Job Card Master` is not the same as `Jobcard Master`. Be more precise and check for typos, your code isn't that bad you're just not precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you do this `Set wb = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker.xlsm")` the code expects that this workbook is already open in Excel. Is that the case? If not you would need to open it from your hard drive using the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open).
2. `Set BodyLength = ws.Range("A10").Value` you cannot use `Set` for a `.Value` because `Set` expects an object but `.Value` is no object. To set a reference to the cell use

   ```
   Dim BodyLength As Range
   Set BodyLength = ws.Range("A10")
   ```

   Now `BodyLength` is a reference to the cell `ws.Range("A10")`.
3. `BodyLength -680` is no valid syntax. If you want to reduce the value in `BodyLength` by `680` you would need to write

   ```
   BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 680
   ```

So finally it would look like this:

```
Private Sub Toolpod_Width_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Automated Cardworker.xlsm") 'make sure to include the correct file extension .xlsm

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Job Card Master")

    Dim BodyLength As Range
    Set BodyLength = ws.Range("A10")
    
    Select Case Toolpod_Width.Value
    
    Case "600"
        BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 680
     
    Case "800"
        BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 880
    
    Case "900"
        BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 980
    
    Case "1000"
        BodyLength.Value = BodyLength.Value - 1080
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks worked fine but I need it to round up to nearest 5